# Ubuntu installation using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

While I try to install Ubuntu in my Mac using VirtualBox I get one confusion for installation.

I create Virtual Drive for my VM of 25 GB and start installation. At Installation time VM give me warning msg that 
" This computer currently has no detected operating system.What would you like to do?

*Erase disk and install Ubuntu"

so what I have to choose?
If I choose mentioned selection, will it erase my Mac OS?
Kindly help me to install Ubuntu without affecting my running OS.

Thanks,
Dhruv

Comment: No. It will format your virtual disk and will install Ubuntu on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VirtualBox simulates a complete computer to the OS it's running. It uses a virtual solid disk (what you called 25GB VM), which is saved in a file on your real disk.

The *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* refers to your virtual disk, so your Mac OS will not be affected in any way. Ubuntu will be installed on this virtual disk and has no possibility to know what's going on on the "outside" - unless you use some interaction features, such as shared folders.

This is exactly the purpose of a virtual machine: To use any operating system without affecting the "host", the OS that's natively running on your computer.